# adding EventListener to multiple buttons doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen posts with seemingly identical code as mine who got it to work, why aren't my buttons doing anything?

EDIT: Copied the entire code instead since the errors must be somewhere else. The previous code seemed to work fine in by itself even in the snippet but I'm getting nothing. I add new elements to the page with getBeers() but I also call the addListeners function after it runs so it should still work the same.

```js
const api_url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers";
let apiData = [];
const newBeers = document.getElementById("newbeers");
const gallery = document.querySelector('.productcont');
const addtocartBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart');
let lastBeer = 0;
let output = "";

window.onload = () => {
    loadBeers();
    addListeners();
}

addListeners = function () {
    addtocartBtns.forEach(function (i) {
        i.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            console.log("you pressed");
        });
    });
}
loadBeers = function () {
    fetch(api_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            apiData = data;
            getBeers();

        })
}
getBeers = function () {
    if (lastBeer === apiData.length - 1) {
        lastBeer = 0;
    }
    let beerName, beerImg, beerDescription, beerPrice, finalBeer;
    finalBeer = lastBeer + 6;
    for (i = lastBeer; i < finalBeer; i++) {
        beerName = apiData[i].name;
        beerImg = apiData[i].image_url;
        beerDescription = apiData[i].description;
        beerPrice = apiData[i].ebc;
        lastBeer = i;
        output += `<div class="product">
                <h3 class="productname">${beerName}</h3>
                <p class="description">${beerDescription}</p>
                <img src="${beerImg}" alt="a beer">
                <p class="price">$${beerPrice}</p>
                <button class="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            `;
        gallery.innerHTML = output;
        addListeners();
    };

};
newBeers.addEventListener("click", function () {
    gallery.innerHTML = "";
    output = "";
    getBeers();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YeOldeBrewery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="../src/assets/js/main.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Click 'Empty Cart' button to clear local storage</p>
        <button id="newbeers">Load more beers</button>
        <div id="alerts"></div>
        <div class="productcont" id="productgallery">
            <div class="product">
                <h3 class="productname">Product 1</h3>
                <p class="description">Placeholder for api</p>
                <img src="" alt="a beer">
                <p class="price">$5.05</p>
                <button class="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*gQwdEeaZFiPNBBGvsLd2LA.png" alt="nicepic">
                <h3 class="productname">Product 2</h3>
                <p class="description">Placeholder for api</p>
                <p class="price">$8.50</p>
                <button class="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <h3 class="productname">Product 3</h3>
                <p class="description">Placeholder for api</p>
                <p class="price">$10.50</p>
                <button class="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-container">
            <h2>Cart</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="carttable">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table id="carttotals">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Items</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>x <span id="itemsquantity">0</span></td>
                    <td>$<span id="total">0</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="cart-buttons">
                <button id="emptycart">Empty Cart</button>
                <button id="checkout">Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You’re not calling the function `addListeners` at all, so no event listeners are bound. You only declared it. You need to do `addListeners()`

Comment: I'm calling it in windows.onload. The function loads up fine since I used consolelog inside it before.

Comment: @gogosimba so if the console log is coming that means the event listener is working, right?

Comment: have you run your own snippet? it does seem to work on the snippet on my end

Comment: @Damzaky yeah, exactly. I just copied this exact code and its working

Comment: @gogosimba its working in the question's code snippet too

Comment: You got it working? That's really odd. I still get nothing.. hmm maybe a browser issue?

Comment: @gogosimba brother, its literally working within the question https://snipboard.io/E3hr8B.jpg

Comment: Please see the updated code, am I somehow overwriting the listeners or something?

Comment: You’re attempting to add event listeners on load, but those elements might not be present at runtime due to a race condition: they are populated asynchronously. Rely on event bubbling instead.

Comment: You can add the onclick directly as well like so:

`<button class="addtocart" onclick="addme('+i+')">Add To Cart</button>`

And if as per your statement it only does not work from your actual code then look for  conflicts which might be overriding the onClick event when you run the same code at your end.

Also consider comments of @Terry that you might be adding listeners to elements that are not fully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this:

`const addtocartBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart');`

to this:

`const addtocartBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.addtocart')];`

Your code should then work. The reason is `querySelectorAll` returns a node list not an array of nodes. By using the spread operator here `[...NodeList]` you are converting it to an array of nodes which `.forEach` can then operate on.

Comment: NodeList supports forEach:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach. No need to spread into array. The issue is OP is attempting to bind event listeners to elements that are unavailable at runtime.

Comment: He's calling it again after he fetches. and you're wrong. That example uses childNodes not `document.querySelector` This returns `undefined`:    `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(d => console.log);`